# Vim through Tmux looks completely out of whack, is there a way to fix this?

Tags: vim, tmux

When SSH'd into another machine, I use Vim as my text editor, and I'm trying to add Tmux to my tool set as well. However, when I use vim through Tmux, the colors are completely wrong, and Vim is unusable. Even when not using Tmux, the colors are slightly off, but it's still usable.

Here's a screenshot of Vim by itself (**not using Tmux**):
[image: Vim by itself]

Here's a screenshot of Vim **with Tmux**:
[image: Vim with Tmux]

There's nothing in my ~/.tmux.conf, and I don't have any color modifications in my ~/.bashrc. Can anyone shed some light on why this is occurring? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked what your `TERM` environment variable is under both bash and tmux?

Answer (score 5):

I've got a solution:

Do this command in each environments.

```
for i in {0..255} ; do
    printf "\x1b[38;5;${i}mcolour${i}\n"
done
```

Though my tmux has:

```
set-option -g default-terminal screen-256color
```

but in tmux, the colour is bad and different  than urxvt (the result in urxvt is same as xterm).

So launch tmux by

```
tmux -2
```

This forces tmux to behave  as if it's running terminal can output 256 colours.

Then run your vim.

Did your problem fixed?

Comment: Thanks! I had my term setup right and had the screen-256color option. the tmux -2 fixed it for me.